# Retrieve Number from a website into Excel

Tags: excel, vba

From this website http://bit.ly/1Ib8IhP

I am trying to get this number into an Excel cell.

```
Avg. asking price in Bayswater Road:  £1,828,502
```

Is there any way using VBA or another tool? Couldn't make it work with a web query.

Comment: as long as the website does not provide an API like access to its data you have two problems to solve: scrape the data of the page (the technique is called webscraping, you will certainly find tools here on stackoverflow) and integrating this with your VBA code. If the page keeps storing its data in something with the class "price big" you might have success when parsing the html for occurences of this marker

Comment: ok thanks that's very helpful. I am on it. Will post my code once I find the best tool as there are too many options..

Comment: There is a Zoopla API - details [here](http://developer.zoopla.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one of the possible solutions:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RetrieveAvgPrice()
    Dim sUrl, sContent, sPrice
    sUrl = "http://www.zoopla.co.uk/home-values/london/bayswater-road/"
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHttp")
        .Open "GET", sUrl, False
        .Send ""
        sContent = .ResponseText
    End With
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "Avg\. asking price[\s\S]*?class=""price big"">([\s\S]*?)<"
        sPrice = HtmlSpecialCharsDecode(.Execute(sContent).Item(0).SubMatches(0))
    End With
    MsgBox sPrice
End Sub

Function HtmlSpecialCharsDecode(sText)
    With CreateObject("htmlfile")
        .Open
        With .createElement("textarea")
            .innerHTML = sText
            HtmlSpecialCharsDecode = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: if I want to extract multiple elements, do you recommend creating additional VBScript.RegExp objects, in terms of speed ?

Comment: It's not necessary, you can assign new value to `.Pattern` property and invoke `.Execute` method again, it returns a collection of matches, if you use capturing groups then each of matches contains a collection of sub matches. You may close one  `With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHttp") ... End With` statement and open new one to make your code more straightforward. Instantiating several regex objects is reasonable if you need to process their matches collections at a time (eg in case of nesting like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30406941/2165759)).

Comment: @JoannaMikalai unfortunately the code won't work since the website content has been changed (here is the the original state [by the link in archive](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20150616061055/http://www.zoopla.co.uk/house-prices/london/bayswater-road/?))